# VLOOKUP or similar to update a cell value using Excel VBA/UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to VBA and Excel and I'm trying to locate a cell using VLOOKUP (or a similar function) and then update that cell with user input, all in a VBA UserForm.  The idea is to have a UserForm that displays table data in text boxes and to then be able to change the values listed in those boxes and commit those changes using a Command Button.  So far I can view the table data using VLOOKUP or even Multi-Column ComboBoxes, however I am as of yet unable to change/edit the data.  I've looked into several options such as Index+Match, but it seems that it might not be possible to reference/update a specific cell using the value of Column A along with the Table headers for column cross-reference (maybe I misunderstand the usage).  I have no available code to show at this time so general ideas of things to try would more than suffice.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample excel sheet where one can search for an Employee using the employee code column A:

[image]

Script for searching employee code and displaying the userform:

```
Sub Find_EmployeeID()
Cells.Find(What:=UserForm1.TextBox1.Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub

Sub forshow()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

In the userform the details comes in the text boxes below the Search button as soon as the employee code is entered and user clicks on Search button and any changes suggested by user is updated in respective cells based on entries in userform by the user:

[image]

Script for searching and updating entries which goes for commandbuttons 1 and 2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Module2.Macro1
UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Value
UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
UserForm1.TextBox4.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
UserForm1.TextBox5.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
ActiveCell.Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = UserForm1.TextBox3.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = UserForm1.TextBox4.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = UserForm1.TextBox5.Value
End Sub
```